# can't find wireless networks

Tags: wireless, networking, connection, realtek

every time i go out of sleep mode ubuntu is disconnected from the internet, which i get, but when i go to reconnect to my router, it can't find any wireless networks at all and it says "device not ready" under the blacked out "wireless networks" i'm using a realtek wireless adapter built into the computer and i'm aware it's not the most favorable one for use in ubuntu but i've installed the driver software and everything. any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you provided the details about exactly what driver you are currently using. Run `lshw -c network` and provide the lines labeled 'product:' and 'configuration'.

Answer (score 1):

`pm-powersave` runs when going into and out of sleep mode. See my answer [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery)